# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el dtype de algunas columnas de mi DataFrame desde object a int? (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, object

No sé qué hice mal, pase las hojas de mi excel a mi consola con `sheet1=wb.get_sheet_by_name('2010')` y después, pasé los valores de cada hoja a DataFrame con `df1=pd.DataFrame(sheet1.values)` y éste lee los datos del DF como object:
    `df1.dtypes
Out[11]: 
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object`

siendo que para las 4 columnas que tengo, 3 son de valores numéricos enteros

`0  1   2   3
MES DIA VIENTO_DIREC.   VIENTO_INT.
ENE 1   270 7
ENE 1   270 10
ENE 1   250 11
...............
0   1   2   3
DIC 31  140 4
DIC 31  140 12
DIC 31  140 16`

cuando uso `df1['DIA']=df1['DIA'].apply(pd.to_numeric)`
me sale

```
    df1['DIA']=df1['DIA'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-15-1324019f27dc>", line 1, in <module>
df1['DIA']=df1['DIA'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

    File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2685, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)

    File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2692, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)

    File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2486, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)

    File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

    File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3065, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

    KeyError: 'DIA'
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar el tipo de datos desde un objeto en `pandas` a tipo `int` se utiliza el metodo `astype`, pruebe lo siguiente:

```
df1['DIA']=df1['DIA'].astype('int')
```